# AndroidPlot real time plotting plot from left after it reaches the the right corner of screen

Tags: android, androidplot

I am plotting a real time line graph using AndroiPlot. I need to restart the plotting from left when it reaches the maximum window. I am able to reset the x axis value to 0 and start plotting from the left. But there is always a line as shown in  the picture from right to left, which I dont need to be displayed in the plot. Could someone please help me to plot it in the right way.

```
private void addEntryGraph0() {
    if (series0.size() > WINDOW_SIZE) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleRatio; i++)
            series0.removeFirst();
    }
    // add the latest sample:
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleRatio; i++) {
        if(xVal1>WINDOW_SIZE){
            xVal1 =0;
            series0.addLast(xVal1, ch0Buffer.get(i));
        }
        else{
            xVal1++;
            series0.addLast(xVal1, ch0Buffer.get(i));
        }
    }
    // redraw the Plots:
    plot0.redraw();
    synchronized (ch0Buffer) {
        ch0Buffer.subList(0, sampleRatio).clear();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is the plot data isn't being cleared properly. Add some logging statements or use a debugger with breakpoints and check that the plot data is cleared when you move back to the left edge of the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the indexing is off; it's not an arbitrary horizontal line, but a line between the last visible point of your dataset back to the first visible point; the last visible point is actually located in your data at i while the first visible point is i+1.  Androidplot simply steps through all the points in your series and draws them based on value.

This code:

```
if(xVal1>WINDOW_SIZE){
    xVal1 =0;
    series0.addLast(xVal1, ch0Buffer.get(i));
}
```

Adds a new point to the end of your dataset that has an xval all the way back at the start of x, which would explain what you're seeing.

One solution to go forward with what you have is to insert a null value into the dataset immediately before resetting your xval to 0; Androidplot will end the line at that point and start a new line once it encounters another non-null value.

However, given what you are trying to accomplish, I'd suggest using a circular buffer instead of pushing / popping.  It will be faster, simpler and behave exactly as desired.

Comment: Thanks Nick!! I have implemented it in another way...  if(xVal1>WINDOW_SIZE){
    series0.addLast(xVal1%WINDOW_SIZE, ch0Buffer.get(i));
}. Both are same effect..